# Taking pictures in React Native app and saving to iPhone storage

Tags: javascript, react-native, image, expo, mobile-application

I'm developing a mobile app on React Native and one of the screens in it is responsible for taking photos:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useLayoutEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image } from 'react-native';
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

const CameraScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
  const cameraRef = useRef(null);
  const [photo, setPhoto] = useState(null);
  const [cameraReset, setCameraReset] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const { status } = await Camera.requestPermissionsAsync();
      setHasPermission(status === 'granted');
    })();
  }, []);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      title: ' ',
    });
  }, []);

  const resetCamera = () => {
    setPhoto(null);
    setCameraReset(true);
  };

  const takePhoto = async () => {
    if (cameraRef.current) {
      const { uri } = await cameraRef.current.takePictureAsync();
      setPhoto(uri);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {hasPermission ? (
        <View style={styles.cameraContainer}>
          <Camera style={styles.camera} ref={cameraRef}>
            <Text style={styles.comment}>Поместите формулу в прямоугольник</Text>
            <View style={styles.formula}></View>
          </Camera>
          <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={takePhoto} style={styles.snapContainerBig}>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={takePhoto} style={styles.snapContainer}></TouchableOpacity>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
      ) : (
        <Text>No access to camera</Text>
      )}
      {photo && (
        <View style={styles.photoPreviewContainer}>
          <Image source={{ uri: photo }} style={styles.photoPreview} />
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    ...
 });

export default CameraScreen;
```

I want these pictures to be saved to the phone's images and then broadcast to another screen. Or  to immediately broadcast the image to another screen without saving if it is possible. I don't want to use a database (firebase for example) because I'm currently in the UI/UX phase, which I'm testing via expo, and it's not compatible with firebase. I need some kind of local storage.

What can I use to solve my problem without using database?

Comment: With local storage it will become difficult to remotely share it, until and unless you are using some remote APIs or 3rd party broadcasting APIs

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: AsyncStorage

React Native's built-in AsyncStorage provides a simple key-value pair storage system. You can convert the image URI to a base64 string and save it as a string in AsyncStorage. Later, retrieve the image URI from AsyncStorage on another screen.

Option 2: react-native-fs

The react-native-fs module is a community module that offers more advanced file system operations. You can use it to save the image file to the document directory and retrieve it later on another screen.

Choose the storage option based on your app's requirements. For simpler use cases, AsyncStorage may be sufficient. If you need more advanced file system operations, consider using react-native-fs.